# Android - elevation in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to add shadow effect to the linearlayout using elevation. Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/searchFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:elevation="8dp"> ---> here should be elevation

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="55dp">

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/fromStationField"
                            android:completionThreshold="1"
                            android:hint="From"
                            android:textAlignment="textStart"
                            android:gravity="left|start"
                            android:layout_gravity="left" />

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/toStationField"
                            android:completionThreshold="1"
                            android:hint="To"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:paddingRight="4dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/swapButton"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_swap"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-55dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_content"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/scheduleListRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/scheduleListRecyclerView"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.standart.trainschedule.FABScrollBehavior"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/fab" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is if I run this on my phone, the shadow doesn't appear but in Preview mode in Android Studio the shadow shows correctly. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

In the relative layout which is a parent for linear layout that you want elevation set these two attributes: `android:clipToPadding="false"` and `android:paddingbottom="5dp"`. Do not make any changes in linear layout.

Comment: where exactly I need to set it ?

Comment: First set it to the layout just above the linear layout you want elsevation for... If that doesn't work set it to first linear layout which is the top most

Comment: it doesn't work, I set it to every layout but it doesn't help.

Comment: You should not do that on every layout... Do one thing remove your padding and use layout_margin instead... Coz of padding your elevation is hidden..

Comment: can you show me it in code please, because it still doesn't work for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong.